# How to show data from this month same month last year same period SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, data-manipulation

I've been trying to get this work. I want to show the data up to date as the days passes I want to display the same day in the same month last year

```
Jul 7 2016     
Jul 6 2016    
Jul 5 2016    
Jul 4 2016    
Jul 3 2016     
Jul 2 2016    
Jul 1 2016  

Jul 7 2015     
Jul 6 2015    
Jul 5 2015    
Jul 4 2015    
Jul 3 2015     
Jul 2 2015    
Jul 1 2015
```

This is my code: right now shows all 2015 records and i want it to show up to date like above.

```
SELECT        
    OrderStatus, Sum_SellPrice, Sum_SellerMargin, Sum_BuyPrice, 
    OrderPeriodMonthName, OrderDate
FROM
    Sum_OrderCharges
WHERE        
    (OrderStatus IN ('Completed', 'Invoiced', 'Open')) 
    AND (OrderPeriodYear IN ('2016','2015')) 
    AND (MONTH(OrderDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()))
ORDER BY 
    OrderDate
```

Comment: Your code should show what you want. Can you let us know what is being returned from your current query?

Comment: Sorry let me delete the code of line that if wrong

Comment: @matt i deleted the line that was wrong, and yes my intention is leave the same restriction

Comment: now simply add @happycoding 's e AND (OrderDate <= GETDATE()) into your where statement and you should have it.  that master..spt_values was causing you an issue and completely unecessary

Comment: @matt that is still showing me the whole july 2015 what i want to do i show the same number of days as 2016 meaning that it should show now 1 to 5 of july 2016 and 2015

Comment: Sorry yes I was focused on that extranous inner join you had..you are correct, I posted an answer that should work for you simply test the DAY() component of the date as well. DAY(OrderDate) <= DAY(GETDATE()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT        OrderStatus, Sum_SellPrice, Sum_SellerMargin, Sum_BuyPrice, OrderPeriodMonthName, OrderDate
FROM            Sum_OrderCharges
WHERE        (OrderStatus IN ('Completed', 'Invoiced', 'Open')) AND (OrderPeriodYear IN ('2016','2015')) AND (MONTH(OrderDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()))

       AND DAY(OrderDate) <= DAY(GETDATE())

ORDER BY OrderDate
```

note `DAY()` will return an integer between 1 & 31 not an actual date so you can just use that to compare and further restrict your results to days that have actually occurred.

Comment: Thank Matt this was exactly what i needed, i was so simple just that line made my afternoon. haha

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would append the following to the where clause:
`AND (OrderDate <= GETDATE())`

Fully it would be:

```
SELECT        OrderStatus, Sum_SellPrice, Sum_SellerMargin, Sum_BuyPrice, OrderPeriodMonthName, OrderDate
FROM            Sum_OrderCharges 
WHERE        (OrderStatus IN ('Completed', 'Invoiced', 'Open')) AND (OrderPeriodYear IN ('2016','2015')) AND (MONTH(OrderDate) = MONTH(GETDATE())) 
ORDER BY OrderDate
```

Not required: I would format it something like the following so you could better see what all you have going on in your where clause. (easier to see all your opening and closing parentheses)

```
SELECT        OrderStatus
              ,Sum_SellPrice
              ,Sum_SellerMargin
              ,Sum_BuyPrice
              ,OrderPeriodMonthName
              ,OrderDate
FROM          Sum_OrderCharges 
WHERE         (OrderStatus IN ('Completed', 'Invoiced', 'Open'))
              AND (OrderPeriodYear IN ('2016','2015'))
              AND (MONTH(OrderDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()))
              AND (OrderDate <= GETDATE()) 
ORDER BY      OrderDate
```

Comment: Hello @happy coding, i was doing something similar but instead of doing inner join to that i was including another select which is not correct, 

question what should i put in 'date2'